# How to page.type a form that requires credit card infomration

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to implement an autocheckout system for fun, I am using hollisterco.com, as an example. the problem I am facing however is that I can fill out ever form in the checkout page, except for the credit card information, and exp date. It fills just 2 maybe 3 letters, then doesnt type in the rest. Does anyone have a solution for this, other than page.type?

Comment: Did you try changing the input's value?

Comment: I mean the credit card number can only be of two types of format. 1. 1111 1111 1111 1111 or 2. 1111111111111111. But when I grab a screenshot of the page after the code runs it only ever fills out 11, or sometimes 1, or sometimes 1111, its very inconsistent. The problem is, every other field works fine, like name, address etc